# JQuery function appears to require refresh on "back" button

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, model-view-controller

This isn't a huge issue, however the web page in interest is used by quite a few people, and this has become a small annoyance for everyone.
I added the following JQuery function to a page on the (MVC)website:

```
     $("#btnHistory").click(function () {
     $(".ActivityDetails").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
 });
```

(for anyone interested, this will fade in/out the div with id "ActivityDetails" on the click of button "btnHistory")

The problem is that people are going into these pages (they are different "support requests" from different customers), they will analyse the information on that page, and then press the browser's "back" button to go to the previous page. Upon pressing this, the screen is blank, and as far as the browser is concerned, full rendered. This can be fixed by refreshing the page, but its just a ball ache to do that 1000 times a day.

PS, this appears to just be a firefox issue.
If anyone has any theories on this please let me know.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting a cookie, everytime it's toggled, to remember the status of the .ActivityDetails div?

Or maybe I have misunderstood the problem...

Comment: I think you have, the previous page doesn't use .ActivityDetails div, it is completely seperate to anything referenced in the function, which is what I find odd.

Comment: So toggling the div on the second page wipes out the content of the first page?  And if you don't toggle the div, the first page remains intact?

Comment: No, the use of the function by the user seems to have no impact, only adding the function in to the source code appears to have created this problem.... strange indeed.

Comment: Sounds random. Do / can you have it live anywhere, so we can have a look?